# Real or imaginary eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question I have been lost in for a while is when will a matrix have either all real or complex eigenvalues? (Depending on dimensions of the matrix in question, complex and real eigenvalues may coalesce, but the question remains the same.) I'm wondering how to recognize them and wish to have a list of different "types" of matrices that always yield either real of complex eigenvalues. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the characteristic equation. I don't know of any standard 'trick' for quickly ascertaining this by inspection.

Comment: If your matrix $A$ is self-adjoint, $A= A^*$, then it will have all real eigenvalues.  If your matrix $A$ is unitary, $A^*A = I$,then all of its eigenvalues lie on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

An eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a real antisymmetric matrix will necessarily satisfy $\lambda+\bar\lambda=0$ and therefore is purely imaginary. As Mustafa pointed out in a comment, a real *symmetric* matrix will always have real eigenvalues.